# Function for linked list producing warning

Tags: c, function, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Function for inserting a node at the beginning of a circular singly linked list is producing an error : `[Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type` at Line 21.

What does this mean and how do I  fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;
node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;

void insertAtBeginning()
{
    int i;
    node *temp = head;
    node *NewPtr = NULL;
    NewPtr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("\nEnter a value\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    NewPtr -> info = i;
    NewPtr -> next = NewPtr;                 //Line 21
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = NewPtr;
        NewPtr-> next = NewPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp -> next != head)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        NewPtr -> next = head;
        temp -> next = NewPtr;
        head = NewPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: `struct node *next;` There is no type `struct node` in your code. Remember that C is case sensitive. You need to use `struct Node *next;`

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Not related to your error: In C it is not requried and also not recommended to cast the return value of `malloc` and similar functions.

Comment: Also not related: write `temp->next` instead of `temp -> next`. That's the usual way it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed the types and `typedef`s. `struct node` doesn't exist, yet you try to use it inside the `struct Node` definition.

To fix that problem, you can put the `typedef` of `node` *before* the actual definition of `struct Node` and use `node` everywhere (not `struct node` since that doesn't exist).

```c
typedef struct Node node;

struct Node
{
    int info;
    node *next; // note: node, not struct node
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the structure declaration

```
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};
```

The tag name of the structure is `Node`. So within the structure you have to write

```
struct Node *next;
```

instead of

```
struct node *next;
```

Otherwise this line

```
struct node *next;
```

introduces a new incomplete type specifier `struct node`.

But in any case the definition of the function `insertAtBeginning` is invalid. The function entirely forgot about the pointer `tail` declared in the file scope together with the pointer `head`.

```
node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
```

The function can look the following way

```
int insertAtBeginning( void )
{
    node *NewPtr = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = NewPtr != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        int i;

        printf( "\nEnter a value: " );
        scanf( "%d", &i );

        NewPtr -> info = i;

        if ( head == NULL )
        {
            NewPtr -> next = NewPtr;
            tail = NewPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            NewPtr -> next = head;
            tail->next = NewPtr;
        }

        head = NewPtr;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to that instead of using the file scope pointers `head` and `tail` you could declare one more structure like

```
struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};
```

and in main declare an object of the structure type like

```
struct List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

because it is a bad approach when functions depend on global variables when this can be avoided.

Also it is the caller of the function that should pass a value that will be added to the list.

In this case the function will look the following way

```
int insertAtBeginning( struct List *list, int info )
{
    node *NewPtr = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = NewPtr != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        NewPtr -> info = info;

        if ( list->head == NULL )
        {
            NewPtr -> next = NewPtr;
            list->tail = NewPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            NewPtr -> next = list->head;
            list->tail->next = NewPtr;
        }
        list->head = NewPtr;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called in main like

```
int info;

printf( "\nEnter a value: " );
scanf( "%d", &info );

insertAtBeginning( &list, info );
```

Comment: @DebottamNath No at all. We, beginners, shoild help each other.:)

Comment: @DebottamNath I have a typo in the first function definition. This statement head = NewPtr; is moved now outside the if-else tatement the same way as in the second function definition.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;
```

This is wrong. There is no `struct node` defined yet. Just `struct Node`.

#### This is ok:

```
struct Node
{
    int          info;
    struct Node* next;
};

typedef struct Node node;
```

Since `struct Node` is known you can declare `next` as `struct Node*`

#### Tnis is also OK:

```
typedef struct Node node;



struct Node
{
    int   info;
    node* next;
};
```

Here `node` is `struct Node` so you can declare `next` as `node*`.

#### Note

a bit *off-topic*, but consider that you are creating a linked list. A list is a list of nodes. **A node is not a list**. If you write the code as if a node is a list you will have extra work and less meaning in the code.

#### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Info;  // here we have a list of int

// this is a Node
typedef struct st_node
{
    Info            info;
    struct st_node* next;
} Node;

// this is a List of Nodes
typedef struct
{
    Node*  head;
    Node*  tail;
    size_t size;
} List;

List* list_create();  // returns a pointer to a new List
List* list_delete(List*);  // destroy List and returns NULL
int   insert_b(
      Info*, List*);       // Insert an element into a List
```

This way we have no need for globals `head` and `tail` and the code can manage any list.

Each node contain an `Info` thing that can be anything, so a `typedef` just before declaring `Node` can turn `Info` into anything, as in

```
typedef int Info;  // here we have a list of int
```

so we have a list of `int`.

And `insert` receives a pointer to an element and a pointer to a `List` so it is easy to manage many lists in the same code.

#### C Example

```
int main(void)
{
    List* my_list = list_create();
    Info  my_item = 12;
    insert_b(&my_item, my_list);
    for (Info i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1)
        insert_b(&my_item, my_list);
    my_list = list_delete(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above creates a list and inserts 1001 elements into that. And does not wait for the user to enter a value each time it is called.